# How can I find the compact trigonometric Fourier series from these signals?

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series, signal-processing

I've been stuck on this for a while, but how exactly would I go about calculating the compact trigonometric Fourier series for both of these signals? I have a general formula down for it, but I just can't seem to figure out how to put it all together for these signals. Mainly, I'm just confused as to how I would obtain the function for the signals just from looking at the graph. I'm also supposed to find and sketch the magnitude and phase spectra. If anyone could help me on this, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks![image: Signals]